# Trouble running windows phone 8.1 emulator on VS 2013 Pro

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to run windows 8.1 emulator on VS 2013 with update 2 but when i do so, it displays following error message:

"Window phone emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running:
Not enough memory is available in the system to start an emulator that uses 1024 MB of RAM.
If closing other applications doesn't help, please follow the instructions on this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911380/en-us

Now, i have created a registry as instructed in the article but still the error remains the same. Kindly help me out

Comment: Sounds like you dont have the 2048M of free memory to start the emulator.  I would shut down any app not needed when trying to use this emulator for debugging.  If that does not solve the problem try using the 512M version of the emulator.

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio and everything else, and then use the Windows Phone Application Deployment tool to deploy any kind of XAP to emulator. That's your best shot at launching the emulator. If it works, then just keep it opened, open Visual Studio and your project and continue deploying to the emulator which is currently opened.